# rest api fetch doesnt display data

Tags: php, json, rest

when sending request get to login page instead of showing data

well im new to this so dont know what to try. used echo var_dump but everything is fine

```
<?php
$username = "*************";
$password = "********************";
$url = "************************************************";

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password),
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$options = array(
    "http" => array(
        "header"  => implode("\r\n", $headers),
        "method"  => "GET"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


echo $response;
?>
```